# Return a List<T> based data from two or more tables in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, linq-to-sql

In sql server, I have two tables (lets say Person and School). I want to return the Person.Name from one table and School.Name (since they are related I want the primary key of the Person also).

So the question here is can I return these data and make them all in a list? also for the return type, does it request that I create a custom type for it (I mean class)?

Edit: Sorry I forget to metion that I need it in LINQ.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is a better way to do this, but I would create a new class and return a list of these objects. Like this:

First do a LiNQ query to get the values we need:

```
var personWithSchoolName = select p from db.Person
                           select s from db.School
                           where p.SchoolId == s.SchoolId
                           select new { p.PersonId as PersonId, p.Name as PersonName, s.Name as SchoolName };

peopleWithSchoolNamesList = personWithSchoolName.ToList();
```

Then loop through the results and add these to a new list:

```
foreach(object o in peopleWithSchoolNamesList)
{
    PersonWithSchoolNameObject personWithSchoolNameObject = new PersonWithSchoolNameObject(o.PersonId, o.PersonName, o.SchoolName);

    ListWithPeople.Add(PersonWithSchoolNameObject);
}

return ListWithPeople;
```

Comment: Sorry, can you explain more why do I need to make the foreach loop? Corrent me if I am wrong but I think it will work if I return the personWithSchoolName.ToList(); since it will return with the same order of variables I need that will match the return type that I will be creating.

Comment: Unless I've missed something you can't return a generic list. You have to specify the return type. And since the peopleWithSchoolNamesList is created at runtime you will be unable to specifiy it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) operation of LINQ to combine data from more than one table

For return purposes you will need a Concrete class. You cannot return the results of LINQ query i.e. an anonymous type, directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Person.Id, Person.Name, School.Name AS SchoolName
from Person
LEFT JOIN School ON Person.SchoolId = School.Id
```

(actually you have to use well prepared linq to return this, yeah?)

and wrap the results into special *predefined* class like:

```
class PersonWithSchool
{
  public int PersonId;
  public string PersonName;
  public string SchoolName;
}
```